# JUnit error AssertionError Value counts differ Expected: 10 Actual1

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, rx-java

I am writing a simple JUnit test in my Android application, I am testing the number of records received but I am getting an error `java.lang.AssertionError: Value counts differ; Expected: 10, Actual: 1 (latch = 0, values = 1, errors = 0, completions = 1)`

Here is what I am trying to test, it is a function which fetches POSTS data from an API.

My actual is 10 as well but I am not sure where I am doing it wrong.

I am pretty new to this, could you please suggest

Test

```
class PostsRemoteDataSourceTest {



    @Before
    fun init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    fun getAllPosts() {
        val postService = mock(PostsService::class.java)
        val postsRemoteDataSource = PostsRemoteDataSource(postService)

        var mList = listOf<PostEntity>()

        Mockito.`when`(postService.getPosts()).thenReturn(Flowable.fromArray(mList))

        val subsciber = postsRemoteDataSource.getAllPosts().test()


        assertEquals(subsciber.assertValueCount(10) , 10)

    }
}
```

PostRemoteDataSource

```
    @Singleton
class PostsRemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val postsService: PostsService
): PostsDataSource {


    override fun getAllPosts(): Flowable<List<PostEntity>> {
        return postsService.getPosts()
            .flatMap { posts ->
                Flowable.fromIterable(posts)
                    .take(10)
                    .toList().toFlowable()
            }
    }


}
```

PostService

```
interface PostsService {

@GET("/posts")
fun getPosts(): Flowable<List<PostEntity>>
```

}

Here is the error message

````
    at io.reactivex.observers.BaseTestConsumer.fail(BaseTestConsumer.java:189)
    at io.reactivex.observers.BaseTestConsumer.assertValueCount(BaseTestConsumer.java:515)
    at com.rao.com.idealarchitecture.data.remote.PostsRemoteDataSourceTest.getAllPosts(PostsRemoteDataSourceTest.kt:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)```
````

Answer (score 0):

> assertEquals(subsciber.assertValueCount(10), 10)

I feel issue lies in this code of line, assertValueCount is itself comparasion check. 
Adding assertEquals over that, causing it to compare with return of assertValueCount function.

So, correct ways would be:

> subsciber.assertValueCount(10)

Please, try this way!

Comment: Hello Suraj I tried that with just subsciber.assertValueCount(10), and got same error `java.lang.AssertionError: Value counts differ; Expected: 10, Actual: 1`

Comment: Check mList initialisation, it's empty.
I think you need to initialisation with 10 values.. that can be return through your mock service

Comment: Tried adding 10 values to mList like this. `       var mList = listOf<PostEntity>(PostEntity(1,1,"Title 1", "Body 1"),
            PostEntity(1,1,"Title 1", "Body 1"))` still the same error